# How to enable dictionary autocompletion without spell option set

Tags: autocompletion, spell-checking, dictionary

I noticed, that in any source code file, regardless of the programming language, I can use the dictionary autocompletion (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>) if the `spell` option is set, if it's not, then the editor gives an error message, "'dictionary' option is empty".

Is it possible to make the dictionary autocompletion enabled without setting of the `spell` option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the following in my `vimrc`:

```
inoremap <expr> <c-x><c-k> SpellCheck("\<c-x>\<c-k>")
nnoremap z= :<c-u>call SpellCheck()<cr>z=
function! SpellCheck(...)
  let s:spell_restore = &spell
  set spell
  augroup restore_spell_option
    autocmd!
    autocmd CursorMoved,CompleteDone <buffer> let &spell = s:spell_restore | autocmd! restore_spell_option
  augroup END
  return a:0 ? a:1 : ''
endfunction
```

The basic idea is to turn on `'spell'` for `<c-x><c-k>` and `z=` and then restore the previous value of `'spell'`. It is a bit clumsy for `z=` when no spell option is selected, but it works pretty well in practice.

Answer (score 3):

The doc [`:h compl-dictionary`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#compl-dictionary) says:

> ```
> CTRL-X CTRL-K        Search the files given with the 'dictionary' option
>                      for words that start with the keyword in front of the
>                      cursor.
>                      [...] By default,
>                      the 'dictionary' option is empty.
>                      For suggestions where to find a list of words, see the
>                      'dictionary' option.
> ```

So you simply need to set you `'dictionary'` option to get the completion you are looking for

Comment: The docs seem to be a bit incorrect, since `CTRL-X CTRL-K` works well even if the dictionary option is empty, if the spell option was previously set. I read the entry for the dictionary option and the problem is that I would like not to create a special file. If there was a way to make `CTRL-X CTRL-K` work without creation of any additional files that would be nice